# Direct vs Sequential vs Indexed Sequential vs Partitioned File Access

Tags: file, filesystems

Can someone tell me the differences between:

- Direct File Access (aka Random File Access)
- Sequential File Access
- Indexed Sequential File Access
- Partitioned File Access

Comment: yes - google. No, really, one is optimized for sequential reads and one is optimized for random access (meaning non-sequential reads). One can almost tell by the name.

Comment: can we reactivate this question now that it's edited? seems it could now make a good contribution to stackoverflow. I'd also like to propose an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better term for "*random access*" would be "*direct access*," since the hardware allows you to retrieve data anywhere on the disc. It is really quite useful! As for "*sequential access*," the hardware is only capable of running through a each piece of data from start to end, and although it may be faster to sequentially retrieve data that is near the beginning of that sequence, it can become incredibly slow if it you want to retrieve a piece of data near the finish of that sequence, since the process has to iterate through each piece of information.

Does that make much sense at all..?

Answer (score 3):

"Random" means you can get any part of the file in any order. So for example, you can read the middle part before the start.

"Sequential" means you must first read the first part of the file, before reading second, then third etc...

From the OS perspective, all files are "random".<sup>1</sup> It's how you access the file from your application that makes it "random" or "sequential". The format of the file may be optimized for one kind of access or the other, for example text is typically "sequential" while database files tend to be highly "random".

---

*<sup>1</sup> On hard drives at least. Files stored on tapes are actually physically sequential, but tapes are typically only used for archiving and you are unlikely to deal with them directly anyway.*

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what level of abstraction you are, and what the elementary elements that compose the "file" at your abstraction are. (Think to "file" as a "`File<T>`", where T is most commonly char)

In generic terms, a "file" is a "Sequence of Elements".
"Random" means you can access whatever element at whatever position in whatever order (essentially, you can jump-around into the sequence).
"Sequential" means that to access a given position you must first scan whatever precede.

Whether this comes from a physical limitation, or software restrictions or "data structure constrains", depends on what the file abstraction is modeling and what abstraction layers are stacked between the physical "sequence of elements" and you.

A file on tape is stored and read sequentially.
A file on disk is atomically read sequentially, but the "atoms" (the disk clusters) can be seek individually, so allowing a higher level abstraction of a random access.
A file that matches a time-based event sequence (like a communication socket) is typically sequential (time cannot rewind), but a bidirectional communication can be used to implement protocols that allow random access (think to NFS).
A memory stored sequence has native random access, but if elements have variable lengths, or are chained in a way that is not determined by address raw aritmetic, only sequential access becomes possible.

The question looks trivial, but if we don't limit our domain only to disk stored files ... a universe of cases opens.